# What should the view inherit from?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am trying to do something really simple here. But I can't find anything in the docs, or on SO, or on http://help.openerp.com

I added a field (which is a many2one relationship with another table) on a form. This created a dropdown menu where can either pick or create new values.

If you click on "Create and Edit", this will open a new window, where you have a field that you can fill in, and save. But the label for this field is "unknown". Someone explained to me that I need to create a view for this form.

So I did, I created this view, at first, I inherited from another form (the users' one), but it throwing me error, moaning about missing fields. My question is: What should I inherit from?

The process works without defining my own view for this, but whenever I pick an existing record, create a new one, the value doesn't appear, but instead I have the name of the table, and its identifier as a link to the record (that will open a new window if I recall correctly). Is there a way to do a lookup instead, and display the value?

Here the code:

counties_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hubclub_counties_form">
            <field name="name">hubclub.counties.form</field>
            <field name="model">hubclub.counties</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <group>
                    <field name="county" />
                </group>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

extra-attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hubclub_res_users_form">
            <field name="name">res.users.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.users</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[2]" position="after">
                    <page string="Hubclub specific settings">
                        <group>
                            <field name="county_id" />
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**openerp**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
    'name': 'Hubclub module',
    'version': '1.0',
    'author': 'Openapp',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'depends': ['base', 'point_of_sale'],
    'data': ['extra-attributes.xml', 'counties_view.xml'],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
}
```

hubclub_module.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp.osv import fields, osv


class hubclub_counties(osv.osv):
    _name = 'hubclub.counties'
    _columns = {
        'county': fields.text(),
    }
    _sql_constraints = [('county_uniq', 'unique(county)',
                         'Country already exists')]


# User
class res_users(osv.osv):
    _name = 'res.users'
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    _columns = {
        'county_id': fields.many2one('hubclub.counties', 'County'),
    }
    _defaults = {
    }


res_users()
hubclub_counties()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Label for the field is "Unknown":

This is because for the model hubclub.counties, for the field 'county', you havent specified any label. You have to specify a label either in python side or in the xml side

In python side:

```
_columns = {
        'county': fields.text("the label for the field"),
    }
```

In xml side:

```
<field name="county_id" string="label for the field"/>
```

if label is not specified in the xml, then by default it takes the label specified in the python side. If no label here in python also, then label will be "Unknown"

2.View inheritance:

Here you want to add the many2one field 'county' in res.users. For this you have to first add the relation to hubclub.counties in res.users. This is done from python.That you have done correctly. The problem made is in the view you have defined in the counties_view.xml. `base.view_users_form` is a view defined for the model res.users. You tried to inherit this view. But the problem you made is that you specified the model for the view as `<field name="model">hubclub.counties</field>` which is wrong because for the model `hubclub.counties` doesn't have a view with reference `base.view_users_form`. Thats why the error  came up. In the extra-attributes.xml you have changed it correctly. For inheriting a view, you have to specify the correct model and inherit_id as the reference to the view along with the module name(For example `<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>` here view_users_form is the view id and *base* is the module name) and the path to the field position.

3.Value to the field is appering as the model name and db reference:

This is actually answered by Odedra

For every model we create we have to specify which field's data should be showed when using this model for relation. By default 'name' field is considered. But if 'name' field is not defined then we have to specify a field which is already defined for this model. For this process we can use `_rec_name`.

```
_rec_name = "field_name"
```

If you want to show 2 or more field's data as the name of the record(for example in openerp if you go to products, then its name will be like variant name, product name, code) then there is a function called `name_get()` which can be used for showing multiple fields data as the name of the record.

Comment: Thank you sir for spending the time to explain everything. Here's your 100 reputation. It was very clear for someone like me who is just started with openerp.

Comment: I'll award the bounty when I can, I have to wait 4 hours

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you could try this:

```
_rec_name="your_many2one_field_name"
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for: `Name of the field in which the name of every resource is stored. Default value: 'name'. Note: by default, the name_get method simply returns the content of this field.`, but thanks anyway